# Eleventy: change Sass output hierarchy

Tags: sass, eleventy

I'm using [11ty](https://www.11ty.dev/) to build a static website and I'd like to use Sass. To do this I've used [eleventy-plugin-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eleventy-plugin-sass). It does compile the Sass code into a CSS file, but it copies the input hierarchy to the output.

For example, in my input folder I have the following hierarchy:

```
input/
    _includes/
    img/
    posts/
    src/
        scss/
            partials/
            main.scss
```

and when I run `npx @11ty/eleventy` it compiles into this:

```
output/
    img/
    posts/
    input/
        src/
            scss/
                main.css
    index.html
```

I would like to have something like

```
output/
    img/
    posts/
    css/
        main.css
    index.html
```

Is this possible using `eleventy-plugin-sass`? If not, what would be another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just released a new version (1.1.0) of `eleventy-plugin-sass` and there you can customize the output directory with the new parameter `outputDir`

Answer (score 0):

Check out these. I set up the package.json scripts based on that, and it works as expected, actually, I copy here my script due some minor changes/extensions:

1. https://egghead.io/lessons/11ty-add-sass-compiling-and-watch-for-changes-in-eleventy-11ty
2. https://mvolkmann.github.io/blog/eleventy/styling-with-sass/

```json
{
    "name": "eleventy-from-start",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "description": "A simple Eleventy starter",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "npm run sass && eleventy",
        "sass": "sass src/assets/css/main.scss:_site/assets/css/main.css --load-path=node_modules",
        "serve": "npm-run-all sass --parallel watch:*",
        "watch:eleventy": "eleventy --serve --port=4300",
        "watch:sass": "npm run sass -- --watch"
    },
    ....
```